OpenSSL refusing SHA3-256 md
I practicing on OpenSSL and Nginx. I created my local root CA, and used it to sign my local server. I made sure to use SHA3-256 to sign any certificate, it is indicated in my openssl.cnf file.
default_md      = sha3-256
I am using this file to sign certificates. That is, openssl ca -config openssl.cnf -notext -extensions srv_cert -in csr/server.pem -out certs/server.pem
If I come to read the certificate, I can clearly read this in it:
Signature Algorithm: ecdsa_with_SHA3-256 twice, once at the top of it, and once at the bottom.
When I run sudo nginx -t, however, I get this
024/08/16 18:59:19 [emerg] 26144#26144: SSL_CTX_use_certificate("/etc/nginx/pki/pkix/rootCA/certs/server.pem") failed (SSL: error:0A00018E:SSL routines::ca md too weak)
I cannot see how SHA3-256 is weak!
Here are the ciphers of my nginx.conf just in case the issue is with them.
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384; # I remember that Nginx did not accept my cipher suit, so i replaced it with this, and then forced my own ciphersuit in the next line. I read this as a solution in another question.
ssl_conf_command Ciphersuites TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
I am using Lubuntu.
I tried to add that line in openssl.cnf to set the secrity level to Zero. It did not work. I added it to the /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf file, and on my local file. It didn't help. I did not try to set it to zero then sign the certificate.
I tried to set the nginx.conf file's cipher suit to the normal one, that is, ssl_ciphers XYZ without the other two lines. It did not help.

You say sha3-512 but show sha3-256 -- which is it? Whether default_md in a conf file, and which conf file, affects cert issuance depends on the other contents of the conf file which you didn't show and the command(s) used and possibly also envvars both of which you didn't show. Do openssl x509 -in /path/to/server.pem -text -noout to see exactly what signature algorithm was actually used. Setting SECLEVEL=0 should work if you did it correctly (which you don't show) and you're NOT on a platform that has system-wide policies like RedHat or (some?) derivatives.

@dave_thompson_085 SHA3-256, I didn't see my mistake in the title. default_md in the openssl.cnf file. Yes, when I run that command I get this Signature Algorithm: ecdsa_with_SHA3-256. As for the platform, I am using Ubuntu.
Pardon my mistakes, I will correct the post now.
